# Discord.py Bot - How to make a bot reply depending on the ping?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and I want to add a feature when I use the command `_userinfo` and mention a user, the bot will send info about the user I mentioned. (Message should look like this: `_userinfo @Name`).

Here's what I have:

```py
if message.content.startswith("_userinfo"):
    emb14 = discord.Embed(
        title=f"@{message.author} info:",
        colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    )
    emb14.set_image(url=message.author.avatar_url)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Name", value=f"{message.author}", inline=True)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Discord Joined date", value=f"{message.author.created_at}", inline=False)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Server Joined date", value=f"{message.author.joined_at}", inline=False)
    emb14.add_field(name="Profile Picture", value=":arrow_down: :arrow_down: ", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=emb14)
```

But the bot sends user info only about that person, who typed the command. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it only sends info about the user who sent the command is because you have `message.author` which means the person who sent the message, if you want to get info about a specific person you could do this:

```
try:
    user = message.mentions[0]
except IndexError:
    user = message.author   
if message.content.startswith("_userinfo"):
    emb14 = discord.Embed(
        title=f"@{user} info:",
        colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    )
    emb14.set_image(url=user.avatar_url)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Name", value=f"{user}", inline=True)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Discord Joined date", value=f"{user.created_at}", inline=False)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"Server Joined date", value=f"{user.joined_at}", inline=False)
    emb14.add_field(name="Profile Picture", value=":arrow_down: :arrow_down: ", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=emb14)
```

what this does now is that if you ping someone it will send info about that user, but if you don't ping anyone it will send info about the person who executed the command